# Class / Function not returning column data

Tags: php

I have a Class to manage the users and everything was working fine until I had to add more columns to the table and modify 2 names. Now one of the modified names, the function that returns the column content is not working, the colum is fill with data but it's not printing anything when I call the function.

I rechecked many times the code, looking for a bad typed name or something, but everything seems to be fine, I can't find the problem...

This is my class:

```
require_once('aet.php');

class staff {

    private $aet;

    private $not_working_column;
    private $working_column;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->aet = new aet();
    }

    private function generate($staff) {
        $this->not_working_column   = $staff->not_working_column;
        $this->working_column       = $staff->working_column;
    }

    private function addInformation($stmt) {
        $i = 0;
        $stmt->bind_result($not_working_column, $working_column);

        while ($stmt->fetch()) {
            $arrayStaff[$i] = new staff();
            $arrayStaff[$i]->setNotWorkingColum($not_working_column);
            $arrayStaff[$i]->setWorkingColumn($working_column);
            $i++;
        }
    }

    public function StaffFromEmail($email) {
        $mysqli = $this->aet->getAetSql();

        if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM staff WHERE email = ? LIMIT 1")) {
            $stmt->bind_param('s', $email);
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->store_result();

            if ($stmt->num_rows == 0) {
                $exit = false;
            }
            else {
                $arrayStaff = $this->addInformation($stmt);
                $this->generate($arrayStaff[0]);
                $exit = true;
            }
        }

        return $exit;
    }

    public function setNotWorkingColum($not_working_column) {
        $this->not_working_column = $not_working_column;
    }

    public function getNotWorkingColum() {
        return $this->not_working_column;
    }

    public function setWorkingColumn($working_column) {
        $this->working_column = $working_column;
    }

    public function getWorkingColumn() {
        return $this->working_column;
    }

}
```

And in the form where users can update their info

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="staff_info[]" value="<?php echo $staff->getNotWorkingColum(); ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item">
    <div class="input">
        <input type="text" placeholder="" name="staff_info[]" value="<?php echo $staff->getWorkingColumn(); ?>" />
    </div>
</div>
```

I've also made a video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9S_Uw7IK_xY

Comment: Where is your table? query ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot. Added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fault, while changing the name of a column I missed one:

```
public function setPersonalPhone($personal_phone) {
    $this->phone = $personal_phone;
}
```

Should be:

```
public function setPersonalPhone($personal_phone) {
    $this->personal_phone = $personal_phone;
}
```